# Problems with Gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I am a begineer in LaTex and absoulte novice in gnuplot. I am using Texstudio and Windows 8.1. The problem is - I cannot make LaTex display a simple image. Probably some settings issue. 
In paricular, I took the simplest gnuplot code from the web (with slight adjustment):

This is the gnuplot code for my graph:

```
reset 
set key inside left top vertical Right noreverse enhanced autotitles box linetype -1 linewidth 1.000
set samples 50, 50
plot [-10:10] sin(x),atan(x),cos(atan(x))
set term pslatex auxfile
set output 'proba1.tex'     
replot
```

This is a file (test1.tex) that I get (besides ps file):

```
% GNUPLOT: LaTeX picture with Postscript
\begingroup%
\makeatletter%
\newcommand{\GNUPLOTspecial}{%
\@sanitize\catcode`\%=14\relax\special}%
\setlength{\unitlength}{0.0500bp}%
\begin{picture}(7200,5040)(0,0)%
\special{psfile=proba1.ps llx=0 lly=0 urx=360 ury=252 rwi=3600}
\put(2340,4236){\makebox(0,0)[r]{\strut{}cos(atan(x))}}%
\put(2340,4436){\makebox(0,0)[r]{\strut{}atan(x)}}%
\put(2340,4636){\makebox(0,0)[r]{\strut{}sin(x)}}%
\put(6839,200){\makebox(0,0){\strut{} 10}}%
\put(5324,200){\makebox(0,0){\strut{} 5}}%
\put(3809,200){\makebox(0,0){\strut{} 0}}%
\put(2295,200){\makebox(0,0){\strut{}-5}}%
\put(780,200){\makebox(0,0){\strut{}-10}}%
\put(660,4799){\makebox(0,0)[r]{\strut{} 1.5}}%
\put(660,4066){\makebox(0,0)[r]{\strut{} 1}}%
\put(660,3333){\makebox(0,0)[r]{\strut{} 0.5}}%
\put(660,2599){\makebox(0,0)[r]{\strut{} 0}}%
\put(660,1866){\makebox(0,0)[r]{\strut{}-0.5}}%
\put(660,1133){\makebox(0,0)[r]{\strut{}-1}}%
\put(660,400){\makebox(0,0)[r]{\strut{}-1.5}}%
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               \end{picture}%
\endgroup
\endinput
```

This is LaTex text:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
gnuplot test
\begin {figure}
\begin{center}
\input{test1.tex}
\end{center}
\end {figure}
\end{document}
```

It might seems silly, but I am looking for the solution for days now, but no luck. 
Many thanks.
Marko

Comment: Your file `test1.tex` is incomplete, i.e. missing lines from the end. Is that really what you get from gnuplot?

Comment: With this setup you have to compile along `latex+dvips+ps2pdf`

Comment: Ok, I hate to answer questions with questions, but do you mind me asking why not `set teminal latex`? It saves you lots of headaches.

Comment: I have a revolutionary (;-)) proposition: Why output gnuplot to LaTeX instead of eps or pdf directly? (Special cases, when special characters needed-> use latex terminal, otherwise postscript enhanced or pdf terminal)

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comments are prompt asnwers. Few lines were missing, I added those now. But there are some weird characters there, in notepad++ those empty spaces shows as NUL. About latex+dvips+ps2pdf compiling, LaTex gives me errors (text line contains invalid characters) so I cannot proceed with dvips and ps2pdf. I also tried output to eps, but again LaTex gives me errors.

Comment: OK, thanks to you guys I managed to find a solution: first, gnuplot did create incomplete tex file, as mvkorpel noticed. I had to write `unset output` in gnuplot and then I got a complete tex file. According to gnuplot FAW, some output formats must be explicitly closed like this.  After that I used `latex+dvips+ps2pdf` as egreg suggested. This solved the problem. Many thanks once more.

Comment: @Marko Could you post that as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, thanks to you guys I managed to find a solution: first, gnuplot did create incomplete tex file, as mvkorpel noticed. I had to write `unset output` in gnuplot and then I got a complete tex file. According to gnuplot FAW, some output formats must be explicitly closed like this. After that I used `latex+dvips+ps2pdf` as egreg suggested. This solved the problem. Many thanks once more.